# Check natural number, validate exception through assertRaise

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-unittest

I have created a little python function which provides a simple check: is the parameter `n` a natural number? How would you accomplish this check in general?

This is the code which I have created:

```
def is_natural_number(n, print_err_msg=True):
    try:
        if not isinstance(n, int):
            raise TypeError("Your input is not of integer type.")
        if n < 1:
            raise ValueError("Your integer is less than 1.")
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as err:
        result = False
        if print_err_msg:
            print("Error: {}".format(err))
    else:
        result = True
    finally:
        return result
```

I'm using Python 3.5. I wanted to make sure that this function always returns `True` or `False` and handles exceptions if necessary. Personally, I do not belief that this code is good, for the following reasons:

1. I'm not sure whether it's appropriate to put the `return` statement into the `finally` block. The code works fine because it always returns either `True` or `False`. However, I'm not sure whether I have caused some undesired side effects by using `finally` like this.
2. I was unable to verify `TypeError` and `ValueError` using `assertRaises` from `unittest`. However, `assertRaises` was successful after having removed `TypeError` and `ValueError` from the `try` block and let those exceptions be unhandled. How can I use `assertRaises` to verify an exception is raised if the exception is raised through `raise` inside a `try` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not raise an exception.

There are two exceptions which may be raised **inside** the function, but since each of them are immediately caught, nothing is raised **by** it, so there's nothing for `assertRaises` to catch.

Here's how I would write your function:

```
def is_natural_number(n):
    return isinstance(n, int) and n > 0
```

If the code calling `is_natural_number()` doesn't need to know why it returns `False`, then *neither do your unit tests*; they just need to know whether it works. Don't overcomplicate things!

**Aside:** Putting your `return` statement inside a `finally` clause is superfluous in your original code. `finally` is for code that must be executed even if exceptions inside the `try` clause are not caught in an `except` clause, which is not the case in your function (and if an exception other than `TypeError` or `ValueError` were to occur in the `try` clause, `result` would be undefined in any case, so you'd get an exception when you tried to return it).